# Setting both $(document).ajaxSuccess and $.ajax().done()

Tags: ajax, jquery, event-handling

I have several ajax calls and when they succeed I need, firstly, to do the same check for all of the responses and then, if the check does not fail, do different things with the responses.

At the moment I'm using `success` option in each of the calls and insert this check in each of the calls, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function (data){
        if (response_has_errors(data))
            {return}
        // do stuff 
    }
});
```

So, I have this idea: use `$(document).ajaxSucces()` for doing the same checking and then use `$.ajax().done()` or `success` option with each of the calls.

But I need the handler in `$(document).ajaxSucces()` to always be executed first, and if it returns `false`, not to execute individual handlers.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should make sure you server does not return a success status (200 OK) when the response is in fact an error. This saves you one step in your processing.

Then you could use [jQuery's `when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to process requests together.

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(...), $.ajax(...), $.ajax(...), $.ajax(...)
)
.then(function () (result1, result2, result3, result4) {
    // all requests have successfully returned
})
.fail(function () {
    // handle error (inspect arguments)
})
.always(function () {
    // stop throbbers or other clean up work if necessary
});
```

Be sure to thoroughly read the documentation on Deferreds if you've never used them before.

Note that you also can pass an *array* of jQuery XHRs using `apply()`.

```
$.when.apply($, allReqests).then( /* ... */ );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no influence over what server returns.  Also, I don't quite understand, in your solution, how do I *first* make the same check and *then* handle responses individually?

Comment: @protasovams If you can't change the server's response code you can (and should) still use [jQuery's *Deferred* architecture](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Here is an example that might clear up a few things. http://jsfiddle.net/XTVxt/

Comment: Wow, many thanks for a great example, it did clear things up.

Answer (score 1):

I could suggest using "dataFilter" from $.ajax(): http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can put some error handling in this dataFilter and if it fails - update some flag directly in the data, and have all "success" handlers check for that flag before executing.